# How to add watermark to video in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm looking for a way to add watermark to videos in Flutter. I prefer not to use the package but if I don't have a choice, then I would use packages. Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Can you use `Stack`? Make the widget blur like a watermark.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [video_watermark](https://pub.dev/packages/video_watermark)

Simple Flutter package to add an image as an overlay in the video along with video trim option.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried that package but it's not working. The progress indicator is spinning infinitely. However I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can put anything above your video widget by put the watermark widget above by using **Stack** widget
Widget structure example:

```
Stack(
    children:[
        Positioned.fill(child: VideoWidget(),
        Positioned.fill(child: WatermarkWidget())
     ]
)
```

From library perspective you can use [stamp_image](https://pub.dev/packages/stamp_image/example) that allows you put watermark on **any** widget

**UPDATE**

You can set an image(watermark) to each frame of video file with [video_manipulation](https://pub.dev/packages/video_manipulation) library

> Adding still frames to an existing video, e.g. watermarks
>
> **.generateVideo(List paths, String filename, int fps, double
> speed).**
>
> Parameters paths list of input file paths. Can be images (.jpg or .png) or video files (.mp4) that are used to generate the new video. E.g.: ["documents/input.mp4", "documents/watermark.jpg]
>
> Parameters paths list of input file paths. Can be images **(.jpg or .png)** or video files **(.mp4)** that are used to generate the new video. E.g.: **["documents/input.mp4", "documents/watermark.jpg]**

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I considered using Stack widget, but the most important thing is that the user should download the video with the watermark text. Do you think it's possible using stamp_widget? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can use video_manipulation  library for this